# Can anyone help me figure out why my Gravatar won't change?

Tags: support, questions

I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing to ask here, but, about 5 hours ago, I changed my Gravatar. I've tried clearing my cache, logging out, and back in, and it still hasn't changed. Does anyone know if there's a specific amount of time before the changes are seen? Or is something wrong?

Comment: Did you associate the gravatar change with the right email that you're using for your account here? There is usually a bit of a delay but only about five minutes, never five hours as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Mana I have experienced hours in delays too

Comment: @badp Ah, okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site hotlinks Gravatar, so there's not really much you or we can do about it. :(

Yes, it takes frustratingly long, but eventually it'll get through. Give it a couple more hours. :)

Comment: Alright, hopefully it'll go through eventually. Cuz I'm tired of looking at the little blue square thing.